# SQL getting max date from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have two tables

```
USER (one row per user)

id,username,firstname,lastname,lastmodified
1,johns, John,Smith, 2009-03-01
2,andrews, Andrew,Stiller, 2009-03-03


STUDIES (multiple rows per user)

id,username,lastmodified
1,johns, 2009-01-01
1,johns, 2009-02-01
1,johns, 2009-07-01
2,andrews,2009-05-05
2,andrews,2009-04-04
```

I want to get users details and the NEWEST date from the two tables:

```
johns,John,Smith,2009-07-01
andrews,Andrew,Stiller,2009-05-05
```

Help?

Answer (score 10):

You need combination of MAX and GREATEST functions here:

```
select u.username
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
     , greatest(u.lastmodified,max(s.lastmodified))
  from USER u
     , STUDIES s
 where s.id = u.id
 group by u.id
     , u.username
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
     , u.lastmodified
```

MAX -- for aggregation, GREATEST -- for maximum of two values.

Comment: If the number of bytes from the user table by which you have to group-by was very large then it might be more efficient to perform an aggregation of the studies table in an in-line view or subquery factoring clause and then join to the users table.

Comment: Just a warning on GREATEST that if any of the values is null, you get a null result, whereas max gives you the highest non-null value

Answer (score 1):

For those who need a simple straightforward select:

```
select max(lastmodified) 
from (
    select max(lastmodified) as lastmodified from USER 
    union 
    select max(lastmodified) as lastmodified from STUDIES
);
```

This will get the max date from USER then the max date from STUDIES, and then it will return the max of those 2. Also you may want to add where clause and some conditions to the inner selections in order to improve the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Users u FULL JOIN Studies s ON u.Username=s.Username GROUP BY Username
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select username, max(lastmodified) from (
   select username, lastmodified from user 

   union all

   select username, max(lastmodified) as lastmodified 
   from studies
   group by username
) s
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
   MAX(updatedDate) as latestUpdated
FROM
    (
        SELECT updatedDate FROM audio
        UNION ALL
        SELECT updatedDate FROM videos
    )foo